# Using Bootstrap DatetimePicker with Sweet Alert 2 - Display calendar over alert

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, sweetalert2

I am using the SweetAlert2 dialog with a form inside. I want to use the Bootstrap DateTimePicker widget.

The calendar widget popup is displayed within the SweetAlert window instead of over top of it. This makes the alert expand and contract - and you must scroll inside the alert to see the calendar. The desired behavior is for the calendar to display as a child of the primary page and display over top of the alert.

https://jsfiddle.net/ghr2bwoc/13/

```
  swal({
    title: 'Date picker',
    html: '<input id="datepicker">',
    showConfirmButton: false,
    onOpen: function() {
        $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({});
    },

  }).then(function(result) {

  });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create an additional class in your style sheet:

```
.swal2-overflow {
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Add this new class to your sweet alert code using the **customClass** attribute.

```
swal({
  title: 'Date picker',
  html: '<input id="datepicker">',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  customClass: 'swal2-overflow',
  onOpen: function() {
      $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({});
  },

}).then(function(result) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are like me and don't want the sweetalert's height to automatically resize when the datetime picker appears. Add a max height and max width (`max-height: 550px !important;min-height:550px !important;`) to @taekwondoalex's answer.

So still add the custom class to the sweetalert  like so;

```
swal({
  title: 'Date picker',
  html: '<input id="datepicker">',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  customClass: 'custom-swal-class',
  onOpen: function() {
      $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({});
  },

}).then(function(result) {

});
```

Then add to your css and change the pixel height to match the height you want for example 550px

```
.custom-swal-class {
    overflow-x: visible;
    overflow-y: visible;
    max-height: 550px !important;
    min-height: 550px !important;
}
```